# Get the max coordinates of a raphael object

Tags: path, coordinates, raphael

I am currently working with raphael.js, is it possible to get the maximal coordinates (the four corners for instance in a square) of a path based raphael object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the bounding box - getBBox();

```
var p = paper.path(['M', 10, 10, 'l', 30, 30, 'a', 20, 30, 0, 1, 0, 40, 10, 'a', 20, 30, 0, 1, 0, 40, 10, 'l', -15, -18]);
var bb = p.getBBox();
paper.rect(bb.x,bb.y,bb.width,bb.height).attr({"stroke":"red"});
```

You'll find an example in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/MDeeR/1/) fiddle

Does that help?

Comment: It's pixels. I've modified the fiddle to show the bounding box around a circle for illustration purposes.